# Configuring PayPal Express Checkout to accept BRL currency

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

When configuring PayPal Express Checkout on Payment Methods, the Default Currency selector don't show BRL as an option.

In the FAQ page https://www.drupal.org/node/1902660#comment-9118725, where we read

> PayPal only supports a small set of currencies, and these vary by
>   service. This module uses the most up to date [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) to
>   populate currency option lists.

on [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) link there are more currencies that Express Checkout accepts. So isn't it necessary to update the set of currencies in Default currency selector?

When I go to paypal site  through checkout button I can't complete transaction because the currency send from Drupal is in USD instead of BRL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2174555) in Issues for Commerce Paypal module. I have applied that patch and now BRL is showed. Going to PayPal page from my site's checkout section now works fine.